# In kubernetes setup using Ingress controller, WSO2 API Manager redirects to 9443 for login flow

Tags: kubernetes, wso2, wso2-api-manager, kubernetes-ingress

We followed below link to setup WSo2 API manager 3.2.0 in kubernetes setup, we didnt configure analytics and we used persistent volumes for mysql and API Manager.
https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/blob/3.2.x/simple/kubernetes-apim/wso2apim-deployment.yaml
whenever we try to login publisher and devportal it is redirecting login url along with port( we configured callback urls in /carbon portal without ports).
it should be redirecting to https://wso2apim/authenticationendpoint/login.do, but it is redirecting to https://wso2apim:9443/authenticationendpoint/login.do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set proxy ports as follows in the deployment toml.

```
[transport.https.properties]
proxyPort = 443
```

https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/blob/3.2.x/advanced/am-pattern-1/templates/am/instance-1/wso2am-pattern-1-am-conf.yaml#L291-L292

Comment: Thankyou @Pubci , Its working  after adding this configuration